# Node js Class Diagram generator

Tags: node.js, npm, uml, graphviz, class-diagram

hello  I tried to use wavi for node js  project t generate  class  diagram 
the  path variable  is set and  the Graphviz is installed correctly  but  it,does anyone  have a clue  about  it ?

Comment: But it... ? Can you give more detail on what you are seeing - post the output?

Comment: error in  Graphviz Class 1   error in <main.js> weird  realy

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, consider using spy.js in webstorm, its a awesome tool